# Javascript change image source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image inside a table cell which is also a clickable link with the following markup:

```
<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer">
    <img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleRed.png" width="20" height="20">
</a>
```

I am confused about the syntax of Javascript that I need to use just to change the source of the image or the image itself and leave the  element and its attributes untouched. I tried this but that changes the  link also which I don't want:

```
rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleYellow.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
```

I only wish to change the image in the last row that was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var cell = rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0];
var allImagesInCell = cell.getElementsByTagName('img');
var theImage = allImagesInCell[0];

theImage.setAttribute('src', '/some/new/value');
```

You can also use `theImage = cell.querySelector('img')` if you don't need to support IE8 and below (see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector#Browser_Compatibility).

Answer (score 3):

You can search for the image element within the table cell and just change the .src property.

```
var cell = rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0];
cell.querySelector('img').src = 'some/other/image.jpg';
```